# WPF RowValidation column of DataGrid placement

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Is it possible to place `RowValidation` column not at the left side? For example, at the right side or somewhere else?

How it looks:

[image]

How I want it to looks:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While I can't confirm this 100%, I don't think that your requirements are possible. There *is* a `DataGrid.RowValidationErrorTemplate` property which enables you to define a custom template to display when validation errors occur, but it does not enable you to specify the placement of it. According to the [`DataGrid.RowValidationErrorTemplate` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowvalidationerrortemplate(v=vs.100).aspx) page on MSDN:

> *The following example replaces the default row validation feedback with a more visible indicator. When a user enters an invalid value, a red circle with a white exclamation mark appears **in the row header***.

```
<DataGrid.RowValidationErrorTemplate>
  <ControlTemplate>
    <Grid Margin="0,-2,0,-2"
      ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource
      FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}},
      Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
      <Ellipse StrokeThickness="0" Fill="Red" 
        Width="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" 
        Height="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" />
      <TextBlock Text="!" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" 
        FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />
    </Grid>
  </ControlTemplate>
</DataGrid.RowValidationErrorTemplate>
```